# Get the "maximum value entered by user"?

Tags: java, max

I need to get the maximum value out of this code, but it's really screwy. Anyone got any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         final int sentinel = 0;
         int number;
         int maxval = 0;
         int count = 0;

         System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");

         number = scan.nextInt();
         while (number != sentinel)
         {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter another number");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            maxval = number;
         }

         if (number > maxval)
         {
            maxval = number;
            System.out.println ("The max value is " + maxval);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `maxval = number` inside the `while` and get the conditional statement inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you overwrite the `maxval` variable every time you get a new number. You have to do something like this

```
 while (number != sentinel)
 {
     count++;
     System.out.println("Enter another number");
     number = scan.nextInt();
     if (number > maxval && number != sentinel) //So you don't overwrite it when you get the sentinel character
        maxval = number;
 }
 System.out.println ("The max value is " + maxval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a bit simpler and fixes the main problem in your code: that the comparison `number > maxval` *has to be* inside the main loop:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int sentinel = 0;
    int maxval = 0;
    int number = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        number = scan.nextInt();
        if (number > maxval)
            maxval = number;
    } while (number != sentinel);

    System.out.println("The max value is " + maxval);
```